# Clipping window rendering to a region

Tags: winapi

I have a window that is 100x100, but I only want to draw 50x100 and leave the right-side transparent without using WS_EX_LAYERED. The Windows Taskbar appears to do this when auto-hide is enabled. The Taskbar is 40px tall according to GetWindowRect, but only 2px is visible. How is it possible to have a window that is larger than what is shown on the screen without making it a layered window?

Answer (score 3):

`SetWindowRgn` makes your window smaller than its `GetWindowRect`.

Comment: It appears the Windows Taskbar doesn't use SetWindowRgn, could there be another way?

Comment: Using this tool: http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor, it looks like the Windows Taskbar uses SetWindowRgn on the Start button when auto-hiding, but not the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

If you look more closely, you'll see that the taskbar is 40 pixels tall, but 38 of those pixels are off the screen.

Comment: That's what I'm asking about, on a multi-monitor setup those extra 38px aren't visible on the second screen.

Comment: In that case, there is a window region. Try it: Call `GetWindowRgn` and see that it returns a rectangle which clips out the second monitor.

Comment: Calling SetWindowRgn on my window forces DWMWA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED to be disabled, and I can't re-enable it until the region is removed. Is there a way around that?

Comment: No. If you apply a region, then you are saying "I want nondefault drawing" and the window manager says "Well in that case I'd better leave you to it and not try to second-guess you by drawing captions and stuff in places you don't want them." The taskbar code is not doing the region thing to get any special effect. It's just a hack to avoid spilling into another monitor.